# What libraries, themes, or plugins are used to create this user interface?

Tags: user-interface

Newbie here and I don't know where to ask this, but could someone please tell me what is this?

[image]

I am really new to this, so my first guess is a User Interface (like jQuery UI)

It is an online drag+drop timetable/organizer where there is a list of activities (with expandable details), which you can filter and add to your timetable and create an activity plan for children then save it or print it.

My Scout group would like to create something similar on our homepage and I would really appreciate some tips+tricks where to start. Our website is a Wordpress site.

(the website is www.gruppenstunde.at, but you have to register, hence the picture)

Comment: That website is blocked, but you're using the term "user interface" incorrectly. jQueryUI is an effects library. The user interface of an application is exactly that--the visual portion with which a user interacts. I think what you mean to ask is "what library is used to produce this UI?"

Comment: (Matt Ball: thx for the edit)
isherwood: as I said, newbie here, but after an hour research I realized I need help from experts:)
Dont know why is it blocked

Comment: No defense necessary. I was simply making the suggestion that you edit your question to use the proper terminology. I was going to do so, but I thought I'd give you the chance first.

Answer (score 0):

I see evidence of Bootstrap v2.1.0. jQuery is therefore required, and jQueryUI is also being loaded, including Draggable, Sortable, Accordion, and Resizable, among others.

- [Twitter Bootstrap 2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/)
- [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) + [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

In short, it's a combination of technologies along with some proprietary graphics and scripting.